# How to prevent "echo" output from being overwritten when leaving visual mode?

Tags: command-line, gvim, visual-mode

I am using gvim 7.4 on Windows (32 bit) and using the [wc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1191) word-counting macro `:WC` by jcline.  When I manually set a range and run the macro, e.g., `:'a,.WC<CR>`, I get the expected `counted XXX words` output.  `:WC` produces this using `echo "counted " . wc_count . " words" . stop`.

Problem: when I select text in visual mode and then run the macro with, e.g., `vap:WC<CR>` (command line `'<,'>WC`), the "`counted`" output flickers for a moment and then disappears at the same time the visual highlighting disappears from the window.  Usually it is too fast for me to read the word count.

Question: Is there any way to leave the `echo` output visible when existing visual mode so that I can use visual mode to select the text input to `:WC`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to the lead from @lcd047, which I greatly appreciate!  I edited the script to run `redraw` before the `echo` per [`:help :echo-redraw`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:echo-redraw).  At least in my particular situation, the message now stays visible until I start scrolling.  The relevant portion of the script is below for anyone who would like it.

```
func JCWC(line1, line2)
  let wc_start_line = 1
  let wc_end_line = 1
  if a:line2 >= a:line1
    let wc_start_line = a:line1
    let wc_end_line = a:line2
  else
    let wc_start_line = a:line2
    let wc_end_line = a:line1
  endif

  let wc_count = 0

  let stop = ""
  let n = wc_start_line
  while n <= wc_end_line
      let line = getline(n)
      if match(line, "^--------") >= 0
          let stop = " until '^--------'"
          break
      endif
      let c = JCWC_line(line)
      let wc_count = wc_count + c
      let n = n + 1
  endwhile

  redraw " <----- Added this
  echo "counted " . wc_count . " words" . stop

endfunc
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't prevent Vim from erasing the status line.  You can however make the output recallable, by changing `echo` in the body of the plugin to `echomsg`.  You'd then be able to recall the results with `:mes`.

Comment: I didn't know about `echomsg` - thanks for the lead!  I found another way but wouldn't have done so without your kind answer (which I have cheerfully upvoted).